# Cannot convert value of type 'SecTrustResultType' to expected argument type 'UInt32'

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2, swift3

Trying run Swift 2.3 code in Xcode 8.0

```
var result = SecTrustResultType(rawValue: SecTrustResultType.Invalid)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Invalid` is one case of `enum SecTrustResultType`, but
`SecTrustResultType(rawValue:)` expects a value of the underlying
"raw type", in this case `UInt32`.

So this would compile

```
var result = SecTrustResultType(rawValue: SecTrustResultType.Invalid.rawValue)
```

but is just a obfuscated version of the equivalent

```
// Swift 2.x
var result = SecTrustResultType.Invalid
// Swift 3
var result = SecTrustResultType.invalid
```